# Where can I find "digital signatures for PDF documents" code download URL?

Tags: pdf, itext, document, digital-signature

Bruno Lowagie has published [this excellent white paper](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures) about digital signatures for PDF documents.

However, I can't find nowhere the corresponding source code with all the examples provided in this book.

Could you publish the URL where I can download this source code ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iText Examples Digital Signatures:

```
Java: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/
C#: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/
```

Have fun!

Comment: To access the source code through SVN, please use the following URL for Java: `http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/tutorial/signatures`

Answer (score 0):

The paper you mentioned was published in 2013. Now, at 2018, the files are located in other servers.

---

**Examples for iText 5**

You may find the source code for Java and C# using the iText v5, in the following URLs:

- The book: https://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html
- iText5 security examples: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5
- source code for the white-paper: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5/digital-signatures-white-paper

  - chp 1:[Digest, Encrypt and Decrypt](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-1)
  - chp 2: [Sign Hello World](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-2)
  - chp 3: [Signing with certificates](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-3)
  - chp 4: [Signing with PKCS11, BEID, X.509](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-4)
  - chp 5: [Checking integrity and Validating certificates](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-5)

---

**Examples for iText 7**

The examples are located in the itexpdf website too

- iText7 security examples: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-security

Comment: You appear to have gotten your headings mixed up.